# Apache Camel Mongodb Connector Async

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Is it possible to use *MongoDB* with *Apache Camel* asynchronously?

I haven't seen any reference for the *MongoDB* async client or the reactive client in *Apache Camel* component documentation (*MongoDB* has an [async client](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver-async/) and also a [reactive streams client](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/reactive-streams/)).

Can Apache Camel connect to it in such ways?

I'm struggling to understand whether an *Apache Camel* channel adapter (EIP) is asynchronous or synchronous. If there's a way to know it for any component, this would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use mongodb with Apache Camel asynchronously?

Indeed, this is what *Apache Camel* will be doing under the cover, otherwise, you will find yourself with an application blocking without proceeding with any valuable processing.

Since you have referred to the *Channel Adapter* (EIP) in your post, I would assume you are trying to implement a *MongoDB* consumer.

To consume data from a *MongoDB* database, *Apache Camel* offers two consumer strategies:

- [Tailable Consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/mongodb-component.html#_tailable_cursor_consumer): This strategy is about having a `Thead` continuously calling for next result on a `MongoCursor`. This strategy is feasible thanks to [*MongoDb Tailable Cursor*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) feature which simply allows to have a query cursor open even after exhausting (iterating) results which removes the need to continuously have the former `Thread` executing the fetch query again and again
- [Change Stream Consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/mongodb-component.html#_change_streams_consumer): This strategy on the other hand relies on the [*MongoDB Changes watch*](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/watch/) feature with which a client can receive (after subscription) changes for a particular collection. Same as for the *Tailable* consumer, there will be a `Thread` running endlessly (unless stopped) listening to changes on the `MongoCollection` of interest

As you can see, in both strategies, there is no need to perform direct queries for changes processing, unless for initial bootstrapping and resumption, neither using the synchronous [*Java Driver*](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current) nor the [*Reactive Streams Driver*](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/reactive-streams/).